# Mobile No getting saved in database and upon retrieval generating 2147483647

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Trying to get mobile no saved in the database with the following html5 validation and on every entry in db insted of the mobile no put 2147483647 gets saved.Please Help.Stuck

```
<label for="su_mobile">Mobile No</label>
            </span>
            <input type="tel" id="su_mobile" name="su_mobile" pattern="^[789]\d{9}$" title='Phone Number (Format:10 digits starting with 9/8/7 )' placeholder="No which you wanna get recharged" required></input><br/><br/>

$yo_mobile=@mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['su_mobile']));




  <label for="fi_mob">Mobile No</label>
            <br/>
            <input type="text" id="fi_mob" name="fi_mob" value="<?php
        $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
            or die('Error communicating to MySQL server.');
            $cool=$_SESSION['user_id'];
    $a="SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE user_id='$cool'";
    $name = mysqli_query($dbc,$a);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($name))
    {
      $queried_name = $row['mobile'];
      echo $queried_name;
    }
    mysqli_close($dbc);
    ?>" readonly></input><br/>
```

Comment: Google that number. It's a column type issue.

Comment: Its a secret code that you have to decrypt in order to proceed.

Comment: How is the mobile number stored in the table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The largest value for `mysql` is 2147483647. Goto your specific table (one storing the mobile number) and change the column's type from `int` to `bigint`.